# Render mathjax dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ckeditor, mathjax

I want to display formulas with MathJax and edit them with CKEditor's [Mathematical Formulas](http://ckeditor.com/addon/mathjax). However when I switch from edit mode to display mode the formulas appear blank (being initially and in the edit mode displayed properly). I've been able to reduce it to a small jsfiddle:

> [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/franciscop/9BCGx/)

Steps to reproduce it:

1. Enter the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/franciscop/9BCGx/). See how the formula is properly displayed.
2. Click on the <kbd>Edit</kbd> button and somewhere in the text. You will be able to edit the formula in TeX and the surrounding text. Note: I'm using for the jsfiddle a CDN without the Mathematical Formulas plugin, however it doesn't affect the behaviour.
3. Click anywhere blank in the display rectangle to hide the CKEditor instance.
4. Now you can click the <kbd>Save</kbd> button. As you can see, the formula is not displayed anymore.

However if you inspect the element you'll see how the initial code in the step 1 and the one after this step is the same but now it's not shown.

The HTML code:

```
<div id = "fullarticle" contenteditable = "false">
    <p>Some text</p>
    <span class = "math-tex">
        \(x = {-b \pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac} \over 2a}\)
    </span>
    <p>Some more text</p>
</div>
<button class = "edit">Edit</button>
<button class = "save">Save</button>
```

The javascript code:

```
$(".edit").click(function(){
  $(".math-tex").each(function(index){
    $(this).html("\\(" + $(this).find("script").html() + "\\)");
    });
  $("#fullarticle").attr("contenteditable", "true");
  CKEDITOR.inline('fullarticle');
  });

$(".save").click(function(){
  var mytext = CKEDITOR.instances.fullarticle.getData();
  $("#fullarticle").html(mytext).attr("contenteditable", "false");
  MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset",MathJax.Hub]);
  for(k in CKEDITOR.instances) {
    var instance = CKEDITOR.instances[k];
    instance.destroy();
    }
  });
```

Edit:

After some testing, I can confirm it has to do to the fact that I'm mixing CKEditor and MathJax, since in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/franciscop/9BCGx/1/) the issue cannot be seen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got it working. Apparently is some kind of timing/order issue:

> [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/franciscop/9BCGx/4/)

The new Javascript:

```
$(".edit").click(function(){
  $(".math-tex").each(function(index){
    $(this).html("\\(" + $(this).find("script").html() + "\\)");
    });
  $("#fullarticle").attr("contenteditable", "true");
  CKEDITOR.inline('fullarticle');
  });

$(".save").click(function(){
  $("#fullarticle").attr("contenteditable", "false");

  for(k in CKEDITOR.instances) {
    var instance = CKEDITOR.instances[k];
    instance.destroy();
    }

  MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset",MathJax.Hub]);
  });
```

However, you cannot edit/save multiple times. Try it, the second consecutive time that you press edit it will display really bad.

Comment: I am following your answer but have some another issue like stored Mathjax equation is not able to load again in CKEditor 4. You also commented in one of my [Question on Mathjax and CKEditor4] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27547100/mathjax-ckeditor-4-ckeditor-in-ajax-based-popup?noredirect=1#comment43521498_27547100)

Comment: @NullPointer is the question the same problem (or similar) to what was happening to you? This problem is also in my answer (as you can see in the jsfiddle) but I accepted it since it fixed the original problem.

Comment: I am not doubting about your accepted answer. I just mentioned that I have similar kind of question and you also had commented in my question for your suggestion. So I want if you have any specific solution to my question. That's it friend.

Comment: And actually your code for `edit` is very helpful for me so thumbs up for that.

Answer (score 0):

Did you see the [Mathjax plugin](http://ckeditor.com/addon/mathjax)? You can see demo a [here](http://ckeditor.com/demo#widgets). As you'll find out, embedding such thing as MathJax inside contenteditable is very tricky, therefore I do not recommend trying to implement it by yourself.

Comment: Yes, the problem is that I also need MathJax as a standalone for whenever the CKEditor is not loaded (normal rendering without editing). I already got that working and saving to the database properly, the only problem is displaying the formula again after saving the data through ajax (because it doesn't render properly, hence my question).

Comment: I don't see a problem - CKEditor produces an output which MathJax understand, so when you load it it's correctly parsed.

Comment: Yes, that's right, CKEditor produces an output that MathJax understands. I have no problem with this when the page is reloaded. However I've found two issues. First, when CKEditor tries to load data from MathJax (try deleting the second line [in this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/franciscop/9BCGx/9/) and iterate several times with "edit" and "save"). Apparently MathJax *eats* the parent element each time it's rendered.

Comment: The second issue is the originally shown in my question. However that seems like a timing issue, so no problem there.