# Mathjax + CKEditor 4 + CKEditor in ajax based popup

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, ckeditor, mathjax

I have configured CKEditor 4 and I have following things on my page.

1. I have one CKEditor in page.
2. Two options to set values.
3. These two options themselves options two ajax based popups each.
4. These ajax based popups contains CKEditor.

Now I have following issues:

1. I have integrated [MathJax](http://ckeditor.com/addon/mathjax).
2. Main page's CKEditor properly shows entered mathematical formulas.
3. CKEditors in ajax based popups first time properly save mathematical formulas but when I reopen those ajax based popups and try to fill saved data (data was save in HTML form) in CKEditor again then no values are shown.
4. I would like to show these mathematical formulas of MathJax to other HTML tags like `li`.
5. Even facing issues displaying mathematical formulas in same page after saving equations in ajax based popups.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Same problem happened to me but without ajax, just reloading the same page, when the mathematics plugin went out. I don't have the code here, I will be able to check it in ~6 hours if I remember it...

Comment: @FranciscoPresencia, I do have issue with Ajax based popup. If you have any solution then please let me know.